# BigQuery: how to group and count rows within rolling timestamp window?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some experience with MongoDB and I'm learning about BigQuery. I'm trying to perform the following task, and I don't know how to do it using BigQuery's standard SQL.

I have a table with the following data. It contains events that occur on different website urls. Timestamp represents when the given event occurred. For example, the first row means, "event 'xx' occurred on url 'a.html' at 2016-10-18 15:55:16 UTC."

```
event_id |    url    |          timestamp   
-----------------------------------------------------------
   xx         a.html      2016-10-18 15:55:16 UTC
   xx         a.html      2016-10-19 16:68:55 UTC
   xx         a.html      2016-10-25 20:55:57 UTC
   yy         b.html      2016-10-18 15:58:09 UTC
   yy         a.html      2016-10-18 08:32:43 UTC
   zz         a.html      2016-10-20 04:44:22 UTC
   zz         c.html      2016-10-21 02:12:34 UTC
```

I want to count the number of each event that occurred on each url over a over a rolling 3 day window. In other words, I want to be able to say the following:

- "on the url 'a.html', during the interval [2016-10-18 00:00:00 UTC, 2016-10-21 00:00:00 UTC), event 'xx' occurred twice."
- "on the url 'a.html', during the interval [2016-10-19 00:00:00 UTC, 2016-10-22 00:00:00 UTC), event 'xx' occurred once."
- "on the url 'a.html', during the interval [2016-10-20 00:00:00 UTC, 2016-10-23 00:00:00 UTC), event 'xx' occurred zero times." (NOTE: THIS DOES NOT NEED TO BE RETURNED AS A ROW. The absence of this row can imply that the event occurred zero times.)

Some notes: my database contains over 100k rows per day, and the occurrence of events varies. Meaning, in 1 day, event 'xx' will occur ~10,000 times and event 'zz' will occur ~0-2 times.

Given my limited SQL knowledge, I didn't want to provide structure for the resulting table, because I figured that might incorrectly limit possible answers. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866033/132438 for a faster solution with approximate results - in case you also need a rolling count of uniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

I am using `ts` as a field name (instead `timestamp` as it is in your example) and assume this field is of `TIMESTAMP` data type

```
WITH dailyAggregations AS (
  SELECT 
    DATE(ts) AS day, 
    url, 
    event_id, 
    UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(DATE(ts))) AS sec, 
    COUNT(1) AS events 
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY day, url, event_id, sec
)
SELECT 
  url, event_id, day, events, 
  SUM(events) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY url, event_id ORDER BY sec 
      RANGE BETWEEN 259200 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS rolling3daysEvents
FROM dailyAggregations
-- ORDER BY url, event_id, day
```

The value of 259200 is actually 3x24x3600 so sets 3 days range, so you can set whatever actual rolling period you need

Comment: That works, let me see if I understand it fully: 1) create an intermediate table that groups and counts events by day. It also converts the timestamp field into its unix second equivalent. 2) sum up the events using a window that is measured in seconds?

Comment: sure, ask if needed

Comment: Couple questions too: 1) is it possible to perform this operation without the intermediate daily aggregation? (ie: suppose we wanted the window to be 10 minutes instead of 3 days).  2) Is it possible to modify the query so that the concept of a day is with respect to a specific timezone, not only UTC? (could we use AT TIME ZONE "America/New_York" with DATE(ts) somehow?) Thanks again... I'm a noob when it comes to BigQuery and SQL.

Comment: Also, this code works great btw. Just to note, it gave a 4 day window, which I can easily tweak to make 3 days.

Comment: 1) sure - daily aggregation made sense because of how initial question was formulated (3 rolling `DAYS`). so easily can be modified for N minutes. let m eknow if you want example or you will try by yourself. 2) easily - see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-types#time-zones

Comment: how could we modify the original query so there are rolling3daysEvents totals for every day, not just the days when events > 0?

Comment: you need to have separate table with all days and then left join it with your query. you can use GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY() function to generate such table on fly. if you will need more help - please post `new question`

Comment: I've been experimenting with LEFT JOINs over the past couple hours and not been successful. Hence, I've posted a follow-up question to stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476728/bigquery-how-to-perform-rolling-timestamp-window-group-count-that-produces-row