# BigQuery: how to perform rolling timestamp window group count that produces row for each day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

this is an extension to a question that I asked and resolved on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289329/bigquery-how-to-group-and-count-rows-within-rolling-timestamp-window).

I'm a BigQuery and SQL novice and I wanted to construct a Standard SQL query that would group and count events over a rolling time window of X days. My data table looks like this:

```
event_id |    url    |          timestamp   
-----------------------------------------------------------
xx         a.html      2016-10-18 15:55:16 UTC
xx         a.html      2016-10-19 16:68:55 UTC
xx         a.html      2016-10-25 20:55:57 UTC
yy         b.html      2016-10-18 15:58:09 UTC
yy         a.html      2016-10-18 08:32:43 UTC
zz         a.html      2016-10-20 04:44:22 UTC
zz         c.html      2016-10-21 02:12:34 UTC
```

I'm tracking events that occur on urls. I want to know how many times each event occurred on each url during a rolling time period of X days. When I asked this question, I got a great answer:

```
WITH dailyAggregations AS (
  SELECT 
    DATE(ts) AS day, 
    url, 
    event_id, 
    UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(DATE(ts))) AS sec, 
    COUNT(1) AS events 
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY day, url, event_id, sec
)
SELECT 
  url, event_id, day, events, 
  SUM(events) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY url, event_id ORDER BY sec 
      RANGE BETWEEN 259200 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS rolling4daysEvents
FROM dailyAggregations
```

where 259200 is 3 days in seconds (3x24x3600). As I understand it, this query creates an intermediate table that groups and counts events by day. It also converts the timestamp field into its unix second equivalent. Then it sums up the events using a window that is measured in seconds.

Now this will produce a table with correct running totals, but it does not guarantee a row for every date, url, and event. In other words, there will be dates missing from the resultant table if there were dates when a given event never occurred on a given url. Bottom line, can I modify the above query (or construct a different query) that will correctly produce values for rolling4daysEvents for each date in an interval? eg: like an interval defined as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST (GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2016-08-28', '2016-11-06')) AS day
  ORDER BY day ASC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH dailyAggregations AS (
  SELECT 
    DATE(ts) AS day, 
    url, 
    event_id, 
    UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(DATE(ts))) AS sec, 
    COUNT(1) AS events 
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY day, url, event_id, sec
),
calendar AS (
  SELECT day
  FROM UNNEST (GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2016-08-28', '2016-11-06')) AS day
)
SELECT 
  c.day, url, event_id, events, 
  SUM(events) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY url, event_id ORDER BY sec 
      RANGE BETWEEN 259200 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS rolling4daysEvents
FROM calendar AS c
LEFT JOIN dailyAggregations AS a
ON a.day = c.day
```

Comment: In order to test this query and look at a single case, I added a "WHERE event_id = "xx" AND url="a.html" to the dailyAggregations query (right after FROM yourTable). I obtained a table with rows for each date, but the rows with no event occurrence yields values of NULL for all columns besides 'day'.

Comment: i see, you wanted to have in result not only missing days, but for all of those days all combination of url and events? is this correct?

Comment: correct, I'm looking to produce a correct value of rolling4daysEvents for each combination of date, event_id, and url - not just the dates when the events occur. If this query is unrealistic to perform, I can look at writing code (non-sql) that filling in the missing info post-query.

Comment: honestly, i think this doesn't make much sense! you should think why you really need it and fix something there. producing all possible permutations physically not the right way! doable, but wrong way to go

Comment: meantime, your question was quite explicitly focused on your issue with missing dates and you dealing with LEFT JOIN - so this part is addressed and hope is helpful for you anyway! :o)

Comment: I understand the confusion and I can see this being impractical. I will looking into post-query solutions.

Comment: totally make sense!