# Moving average last 30 days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to find the number of unique users active in the last 30 days. I want to calculate this for today, but also for days in the past. The dataset contains user ids, dates and events triggered by the user saved in BigQuery. A user is active by opening a mobile app triggering the event session_start. Example of the unnested dataset.

```
| resettable_device_id |     date    |    event      |
------------------------------------------------------
|         xx           |  2017-06-09 | session_start |
|         yy           |  2017-06-09 | session_start |
|         xx           |  2017-06-11 | session_start |
|         zz           |  2017-06-11 | session_start |
```

I found a solution which suits my problem:
[BigQuery: how to group and count rows within rolling timestamp window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289329/bigquery-how-to-group-and-count-rows-within-rolling-timestamp-window)

My BigQuery script so far:

```
#standardSQL
WITH daily_aggregation AS (
  SELECT 
    PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", event_dim.date) AS day,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.device_info.resettable_device_id) AS unique_resettable_device_ids
  FROM `ANDROID.app_events_*`,
    UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
  WHERE event_dim.name = "session_start"
  GROUP BY day
)
SELECT 
  day, 
  unique_resettable_device_ids, 
  SUM(unique_resettable_device_ids) 
  OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(day)) DESC ROWS BETWEEN 2592000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS unique_ids_rolling_30_days
FROM daily_aggregation
ORDER BY day
```

This script results in the following table:

```
|      day   | unique_resettable_device_ids | unique_ids_rolling_30_days |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-06-05 |            1807              |            2614            |
| 2018-06-06 |             711              |             807            |
| 2018-06-07 |              96              |              96            |
```

The problem is that the column unique_ids_rolling_30_days is just a cumulative sum of the column unique_resettable_device_ids. How can I fix the rolling window function in my script?

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer and accept it yourself. This would be clearer for people who find this question.

Comment: Removed the solution from the original question and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution for a weekly calculation of the number of active users in the last 30 days.

```
#standardSQL
WITH days AS (
  SELECT day 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) AS day
), periods AS (
SELECT 
  DATE_SUB(days.day, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS StartDate,
  days.day AS EndDate FROM days
)
SELECT
  periods.EndDate AS Day,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.device_info.resettable_device_id) as resettable_device_ids
FROM `ANDROID.app_events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_dim) AS event_dim
CROSS JOIN periods
WHERE
  PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", event_dim.date) BETWEEN periods.StartDate AND periods.EndDate
  AND event_dim.name = "session_start"
GROUP BY Day
ORDER BY Day DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

"The problem is that the column unique_ids_rolling_30_days is just a cumulative sum of the column unique_resettable_device_ids."

Of course, as that's exactly what the code

`SUM(unique_resettable_device_ids) 
  OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(day)) DESC ROWS BETWEEN 2592000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS unique_ids_rolling_30_days`

is asking for.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/49866033/132438 where the question asks about specifically counting uniques in a rolling window: Turns out it's a very slow operation given how much memory it requires.

The solution for this when you want a rolling count of uniques: Go for approximate results.

From the linked answer:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL i DAY) date_grp
 , HLL_COUNT.MERGE(sketch) unique_90_day_users
 , HLL_COUNT.MERGE(DISTINCT IF(i<31,sketch,null)) unique_30_day_users
 , HLL_COUNT.MERGE(DISTINCT IF(i<8,sketch,null)) unique_7_day_users
 , COUNT(*) window_days
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(creation_date) date, HLL_COUNT.INIT(owner_user_id) sketch
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` 
  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation_date)=2017
  GROUP BY 1
), UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 90)) i
GROUP BY 1
HAVING window_days=90
ORDER BY date_grp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I transformed your code to my use case, but the outcome of the script did not match with a validation script. My validation script is just the number of active users in a window from today to 30 days in the past. Someone helped me to find another solution, which you can find in my updated post.

Comment: Sorry, I added the solution. It works now on a weekly basis for calculating the number of active users.